# How to get day and date?

Tags: objective-c, iphone

i want to get date in 2 labels like this
Label1:-> Tuesday
Label2:-> 2 June 2010

how can i get this value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code will get you the strings you require to set the labels:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *weekdayFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setDateFormat: @"d MMMM yyyy"];
[weekdayFormatter setDateFormat: @"EEEE"];
NSString *formattedDate = [formatter stringFromDate: today];
NSString *weekday = [weekdayFormatter stringFromDate: today];
```

The date formatters are controlled through this standard: [Unicode Date Formats](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Answer (score 4):

```
[label1 setText:@"Tuesday"];
[label2 setText:@"2 June 2010"];
```

Or did you need something different?

Comment: +1: Only he asked how to get the value: `NSString *str = [label1 text]` :p

Answer (score 2):

Hello You can get Day and Date From this code 
and here weekday give you the day Example: Monday,Tuesday for re

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *weekdayFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setDateFormat: @"d MMMM yyyy"];
[weekdayFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
[weekdayFormatter setDateFormat: @"EEEE"];
NSString *formattedDate = [formatter stringFromDate: today];
NSString *weekday = [weekdayFormatter stringFromDate: today];
```

Answer (score 0):

In swift, you can do like that:

```
    let today = Date()
    let weekdayFormatter = DateFormatter()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "d MMMM yyyy"
    weekdayFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
    let formattedDate = formatter.string(from: today)
    let weekday = weekdayFormatter.string(from: today)
```